# How to compress PDF file that is generated using HTML-Renderer library c#

Tags: c#, pdf, pdfsharp

i have the following code which is working fine. I am generating `pdf`file through `html` content using library `HTML-Randerer`. Problem is that  generated `pdf` file size become increases up to aprox 8MB some time.and i wanted to compress that file as i have to send this `pdf` to some of the client . I have searched but did not find any solution.

**Note:"Html content has no image just tag and textual data only "**

Library:
[HTML Renderer](https://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/documentation)

Question: How to compress the pdf file using `HTML Renderer` is there any method ?

Code

```
public void GenerateHtmlToPdf(string htmlContent, string sFilePath)
    {
        PdfDocument pdf = PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(htmlContent, PageSize.A4, 25);
        pdf.Save(sFilePath);

    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why down vote kindly explain me?

Comment: PdfGenerator is not part of PDFsharp and I don't know what it does. PDFsharp has a few options that control the size of the file. Without seeing a PDF file I cannot say why you get large files. The PDF file will include the required fonts. With several different fonts this can be several MiB. Just speculation without a PDF file to look at.

Comment: @ThomasH here` https://github.com/ArthurHub/HTML-Renderer/blob/master/Source/HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp/PdfGenerator.cs` PdfGenerator is a part of PDFsharp . i don't know how you say that `PdfGenerator` is not part of `PDFsharp`.

Comment: and i will upload pdf `sample` which i'm generating through `html`

Comment: PdfGenerator is not part of PDFsharp. See here: https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp

Comment: @ThomasH here is a `pdf` please do look at it and suggest me a direction. [Pdf file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lgjkihqdofrdhwu/foo.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: @ThomasH after studying your link [PDFsharp](https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp) i am come to the conclusion that i am **WRONG ** `pdfGenerator` is not a part of  `PDFsharp` but  is of `HTML Renderer` library. so now i have  updated my question. and thanks for pointing the mistake..

Comment: Is the HTML file all you got? You should get much smaller PDF files if you create the PDF using MigraDoc directly, using data from e.g. a database.

Comment: @PDFsharpTeam no i have to generate the `PDF` from `html` as i have to send html along with the `pdf` its a client requirement

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can't do it with pdfsharp. And because you don't use images, there is no help there either in that direction. You may read up on alternatives in another post [Compress existing PDF using C# programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719553/compress-existing-pdf-using-c-sharp-programming-using-freeware-libraries)

Comment: Thanks for reply ..The link which you posted is not what i need ., i have clearly mention  in question that i need some function in `pdfsharp` library if there exists to compress file .

Answer (score 1):

The PDF "foo.pdf" you provide contains 33 pages, each pages is between 150 kB to 350 kB in size.

Each page draws hundreds of lines. Maybe the library draws four lines around each cell. The same visual effect could be achieved with a few, long lines which would reduce the file size considerably.

There are many PDF Optimizer and PDF Compacter around, but I'm afraid they won't do much good with that file.

Comment: Thanks for reply :) . oky i'm trying to change the style . then i will tell you what the  result ..

Comment: [foo_TestFile1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/08968hp3wt7iywp/foo_Test1.pdf?dl=0) .here is a file .i have changed the style (even style is removed) . file size is now decreases to `3.9MB` (Original size was 11MB ). but i need more size reduction  .Is there any thing else that i can do to reduce more size?